# Exceptions: How can I get the most possible information?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, reflection

I have an enterprise application that logs exception information whenever one happens to occur. The application is a combination of C#, and C++.net.

I want to get *as much* information as I can at the time of the exception.  As of right now, we only print out the Message and the stack trace (which gives line numbers in debug builds, but not release).

The goal of any error log is to point out the error to the best of its ability (as close as it can get).  I'm curious how I can take this farther?  I want more info.

As a for-instance, I know NullReferenceExceptions and InvalidArguementExceptions contain different amounts of information, but I'm not harnessing anything besides the 'Message' Field.

Is my best bet to use reflection and capture all the public members and print them out?  Or perhaps chain TONS of type-checks and casts to print them out cleanly?  As a constraint, my logging function needs to just take in an argument of type Exception.

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on the exception object is usually sufficient for my needs.  This gives me the exception type, message, and stack trace.

Comment: Those things are all useful, however, I'm running into issues where we get a null reference exception in the middle of a very large scale algorithm.  In this case, a nullreferencexception contains the datatype of the variable that threw the exception, it would be great to get that information!

Comment: I'm not concerned with handling and recovering from the exceptions currently.  Right now I'm just trying to optimize our exception logger to contain more information.

Comment: Do you loop through the inner exceptions making a note of those when logging the exception itself to give you the most information possible?

Comment: @James, No, I don't.  Thats a great idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, the answer is to log ex.ToString(). In general, the ToString method of an object displays what the object wants you to know. In the case of the base Exception class, this includes the message and stack trace, in addition to the same for any InnerException instances. Particular derived classes of Exception may display more information.

Some exceptions like SqlException also capture additional information (like the stored procedure name and linenumber). In these cases, it it helpful to serialize the entire exception and save that as XML in your logging database. Note that not all exception classes can be serialized, so be prepared to punt on the XML portion.

Also, if all you're doing is logging the exception, then you may want to rethrow the exception so that higher levels can have a chance to handle it. Of course, this does not apply when you are already at the "top level".

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try:

```
try 
{
    //...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Messagebox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

It shows a lot of information, including **exception type**, **message** and **stack trace** of all the exeptions (the `InnerException` of all the exceptions ordered).

More information in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

Comment: `ex.ToString()` gives very much information _unless_ someone overrode the `ToString` method in a specialized class and forgot to give all info in his `override`.

Comment: Why the downvote? ex.ToString() is the correct method to get all the information the exception wants you to know about?

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static string ErrorManager(Exception ex, bool ShowPopUp, bool CrashProgram)
    {
        string stack = ex.StackTrace;
        string source = ex.Source;
        string message = ex.Message;
        string LF = Environment.NewLine;

        string Error = $"A crash happen at {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}{LF}" +
                       $"This is what crashed: {source}{LF}" +
                       $"This is the error message : {LF}{message}{LF + LF}" +
                       $"These are the last instructions executed before the crash : {LF}{stack}{LF + LF}";

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Error += $"Inner Exception : {LF}{ex.InnerException.Message}";
        }

        if (ShowPopUp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Error, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

        if (CrashProgram)
        {
            throw new Exception(Error);
        }
        return Error.Trim();
    }
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.